# How to decide whether the sentence is negative?

Tags: negation

Sorry for a very general question, but it's important for me to know *the alpha and omega* of it! The question came to my mind looking at [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/21464/use-of-everything-and-anything).

I searched on Oxforddictionaries and landed here.

[image: Negative Sentences]

**Now the question:**

All the examples for *negative or in questions* and *without negative* reflect *negativeness* one or the other way.

Does negation only imply to the *subject* and never the results? *I was ready for my resignation (is positive?)* OVER *I wasn't ready for my promotion and thus declined it! (is negative?)*

**My homework:** I went through [this](http://www.whitesmoke.com/negative-sentences) but still it's not utterly clear. What if **there's no subject!** Can we come up with negative/positive sentences then?

For instance, *this produces **no** results - negative?

Comment: It's all about negative polarity. (Not to be confused with words that have negative connotation.) Recommended reading: http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf

Comment: coming from the Hagu master...I'll surely read. Enhancing knowledge in process... Thankss!

Answer (score 1):

A sentence becomes negative by specific words. Most of those have 'no' in it. For example

```
No
Nobody
No one
Never
Not
Nowhere
...
```

And yes a sentence without a subject can be negative. Here's an example:

```
Stop the car!  -- positive
Do not stop the car! -- negative

Do your homework!
Don't do drugs!
```

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to the licensing of words like *anything*, I don't think it's helpful to think of negation as being a property of a *sentence*, per se. The *no* in "This produces no results" is certainly negative (we can say "This produces no results of any consequence", with *any*), but that doesn't extend backward to the subject (we can't say *"Anything produces no results") or verb (we can't say *"This ever produces no results").

A good rule of thumb is that the negative word must come *before* any words that it licenses. So, for example, we can say "No one ever saw it" (*no one* before *ever*) or "Never did anyone see it" (*never* before *anyone*; though note that this is a bit formal or literary), but we can't say *"Anyone never saw it" (*anyone* before *never*), nor *"Ever did no one see it" (*ever* before *no one*).